# login validate form. Help on JS function

Tags: javascript, html, validation, modal-dialog

After the tips I change signup/signin. Now its with mysql/php.

but I have another little problem. I made javascript validation form for check username( only letters) and password ( >4 not empty ). All fine but the php script start anyway, even if username is not only letters or password is <4 char.

actually the part of code prolly I need change are this HTML

```
                    <form name="LogForm" action="http://localhost/ecommerce/assets/login.php" class="login__registre" method="post" id="login-in">

                    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="Submit" id="login__test" onclick="validateLog()">
```

or Javascript

```
enter function validateLog(){ 
var usexname = document.LogForm.usex; 
var pwk = document.LogForm.pwx;
if(alphanumeric(usexname))
{if(pwd_validation(pwk, 4, 20)){
}}return false;} ........
```

and the code continue with the alphanumeric and pwd_validation, both work.

what I need is prolly change onclick function in html, with another function that include validateLog(). Only if validateLog() is full true I can run the new function and start the php signin.

Actually cant find a way for do that, maybe can like me something can help ?
I'm probably looking for the wrong material on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http error 405 means that the request (POST in this case) is not allowed by the server, and what you are doing is really really dangerous, never check connection information with client-side javascript because the password and username are visible in the source code, and you can access the admin page directly without password, check connection informations with a backend language such as php, perl...

Comment: Was a test website but thanks, I completely changed my plan and did signup/signin by PHP. Only a simple validation form onclick with javascript.